# How would you open an activity depending on a database result

Tags: java, android, artificial-intelligence

What I am looking to do is:

Firstly, I will be creating a database (SQLite) and I will be storing locations of landmarks, how much it costs to go there, duration of time needed etc. and of course an ID.

Now this is what I want to do, I am trying to do a really simple and basic recommendation system which will take input from the user e.g. 
Location = London, Cost = Free, Duration = < 2 hours
So I will execute the query and search the database for the above, and then I will choose the first result and this should open up an activity to the correct landmark.

For example, I have a Big Ben activity, they do the above and the result of the SELECT statement will be 'Big Ben' how do I now get this to open the activity I have created in regards to this place already?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a category activity and what you want to do is to click some item then select one item and that item is passed to next activity name sub-category
when you click one item - the subitem which are related to category will be displayed in the next category 
here is how you can achieve that

In category activity

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Category category = categorylist.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SubCategoryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("CategoryID",String.valueOf(category.getCategoryid()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

now when an item is clicked it will be picked and then we forward it's id  to next activity using activity.putextra
and launch that activity

in next activity we will catch this element

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //CREATE AND INFLATE THE VIEW
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcategory);

    //GET THE INTENT AND CATEGORYID
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String CategoryID = intent.getStringExtra("CategoryID");        
}
```

now we have got this categoryid - now you can query using this id and show results

whenever you click any item in category activity - the next activity will launch and show you the results